# Google Analytics - exclude hits on specific page

Tags: google-analytics, bots

I set up a Google Analytics account recently, and continuously getting hits from a Russian address. The same issue is described here: http://www.wiyre.com/google-analytics-darodar-forum-spam-what-is-it/ but the recommended solution do not work for me (bot filtering).

I recognized though that these hits all happen on the same page: "/". Is it possible to exclude hits based on the page?

Comment: you can setup an exclude filter where the page is "/", yes.  However, I assume that is your homepage and you have tracking on it on purposes.. setting up a filter based on the page name will exclude *all* traffic to it, even legit traffic.  It sounds like you know the (ip) address.. why doesn't bot filtering work for you? Alternatively, you can setup a filter to exclude by ip address if you do indeed know it.

Comment: I use google analytics to monitor the usage of a Chrome Extension - no pageviews are sent, only events. Excluding all pageviews is a suitable solution for me. I set up a filter to exclude them, but sill see the pageviews in my statistics (I clicked on: Custom filter type - exclude - Hit Type - Filter Pattern "pageview")